# Unable to resolve standard java imports

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I am a Java newbie, pretty new to Eclipse/OSGi etc.

I am trying to run a OSGi bundle. I have installed all the dependent jars in OSGi.
But while starting the bundle in the OSGi console, I am getting the following errors:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved.  
Reason:Missing Constraint:Require-Bundle:org.eclipse.xtext;bundle-version="0.0.0"
```

The standard imports are not resolved. How can I resolve this issue?
Let me know if I should post more information.

```
osgi> diag 24
file:///C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\RuleEngineDependency  
\org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025.jar [24]
**Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi_[3.7.0,4.0.0).**
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.6.100,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.0.0.
Missing imported package org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth_0.0.0.

osgi> install file:///C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\RuleEngineDependency   \org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
Bundle id is 25

osgi> diag 25
file:///C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\RuleEngineDependency\org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar [25]
No unresolved constraints.

osgi> diag 24
file:///C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\RuleEngineDependency\org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.8.0.v20120912-155025.jar [24]
**Missing required bundle org.eclipse.osgi_[3.7.0,4.0.0).**
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common_[3.6.100,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.jobs_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.registry_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.contenttype_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.0.0.
Missing imported package org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.auth_0.0.0.
```

Even after adding org.eclipse.osgi bundle, it is till listing as missing dependency.

Comment: I'm not sure but see if this can be of any help: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/317016/

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle is not misssing a standard java import. The bundle manifest contains the Require-Bundle directive and so the bundle will only resovle once the org.eclipse.xtext bundle is deployed. As this directive is not added automatically you must have either added it by hand or perhaps copied from another Manifest.

Does your bundle really require xtext? If yes then you have to deploy the extext bundle into the OSGi environment. If not then remove the Require-Bundle header and it should work.

Comment: How do I deploy org.eclipse.xtext bundle?

Comment: @ChristianScheider I deployed `org.eclipse.xtext_2.3.0`. But still it is not resolved. It is looking for `org.eclipse.xtext_0.0.0`. How can I get `0.0.0`?

Comment: 0.0.0 means any. make sure you have all required bundles for org.eclipse.xtext_2.3.0 and it can be resolved? (you can investigate through (host) osgi console.

Comment: That xtext misses somes of its own dependencies sounds like a very possible reason for the problem.

Comment: Even if your bundle depends on stuff from xtext, [you should try to avoid the `Require-Bundle` header](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Use_Import-Package_instead_of_Require-Bundle). Use proper `Import-Package` directives to widen the constraint to a specific package being provided (by _any_ bundle) instead of requiring a specific bundle.

Comment: Hmm, this is going like a chain reaction.. I add one bundle to satisfy previous bundle. The new bundle has newer set of dependencies. When will this stop. This is a huge manual effort.Is this how OSGi works?

Comment: I would suggest looking into eclipse's support for  [target platforms](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html), which should at the minimum allow you to find out any missing dependencies (including transitive dependencies).